# border-dashed в мобильном устройстве

Tags: html, css

Я всё перепробовал, может кто-то из Вас знает? В смартфоне почему-то border: dashed; вокруг названия "Все работы" показывается так, как на скриншоте, а должен вокруг, как здесь: [http://svisotsky.microlines.lv](https://web.archive.org/web/20130227004607/http://svisotsky.microlines.lv:80/).

[http://svisotsky.microlines.lv/img/src.png http://svisotsky.microlines.lv/img/src.png](http://svisotsky.microlines.lv/img/src.png)

Притом для всех устройств указано одинаково border: dashed 2px #999;
А на планшете всё нормально.

Comment: какая версия ОС?

Comment: 4.0 ice cream sandwitch. На планшете такая же, но там всё работает. Вот кстати и сам сайт, я уже залил адаптивный: http://svisotsky.microlines.lv/, если не сложно и если у Вас есть смартфон, посотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: На Android 2.3.7 линия сплошная, на iOS всё ок. Других устройств нет.

Comment: Понятно! спасибо!